# Unable to run Grails project using Spring Security Core in GGTS on Windows 7

Tags: spring-security, grails-plugin, grails-2.2

I’m new to Grails and I’m trying desperately to get the Spring Security plugin to run. I added the following line to my project’s `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
plugins{
    ... 
    compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3" 
    ...
}
```

Then I tried to install the plugin via the `install-plugin` command. No matter which way I choose, I cannot launch the project now that I’ve run the `s2-quickstart` script (which [creates the Spring Security domain classes and controllers](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/ref/Scripts/s2-quickstart.html)).

I’m using PostgreSQL as a database and running Groovy/Grails Tool Suite on Windows 7, with Grails version 2.2.1.

This is the error message:

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.1
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application....
| Compiling 7 source files.....
| Running Grails application

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

| Error 2013-03-29 22:15:17,677 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'instanceTagLibraryApi': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.TagLibraryApi.setGspTagLibraryLookup(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.TagLibraryLookup); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gspTagLibraryLookup': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib.linkGenerator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsLinkGenerator': Post-processing failed of bean type [class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.CachingLinkGenerator] failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26 cannot be cast to java.lang.annotation.Annotation
Message: Error creating bean with name 'instanceTagLibraryApi': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.TagLibraryApi.setGspTagLibraryLookup(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.TagLibraryLookup); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gspTagLibraryLookup': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib.linkGenerator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsLinkGenerator': Post-processing failed of bean type [class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.CachingLinkGenerator] failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26 cannot be cast to java.lang.annotation.Annotation
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.TagLibraryApi.setGspTagLibraryLookup(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.TagLibraryLookup); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gspTagLibraryLookup': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib.linkGenerator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsLinkGenerator': Post-processing failed of bean type [class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.CachingLinkGenerator] failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26 cannot be cast to java.lang.annotation.Annotation
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gspTagLibraryLookup': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib.linkGenerator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsLinkGenerator': Post-processing failed of bean type [class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.CachingLinkGenerator] failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26 cannot be cast to java.lang.annotation.Annotation
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib.linkGenerator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsLinkGenerator': Post-processing failed of bean type [class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.CachingLinkGenerator] failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26 cannot be cast to java.lang.annotation.Annotation
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib.linkGenerator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsLinkGenerator': Post-processing failed of bean type [class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.CachingLinkGenerator] failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26 cannot be cast to java.lang.annotation.Annotation
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsLinkGenerator': Post-processing failed of bean type [class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.CachingLinkGenerator] failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26 cannot be cast to java.lang.annotation.Annotation
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26 cannot be cast to java.lang.annotation.Annotation
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

**EDIT:**
Running the app using `run-app --verbose --stacktrace` results in a successful server launch, but the process does not finish in the background. After a short time, the server shuts down with an error:

```
run-app --verbose --stacktrace encountered a problem

timelimit was exceeded.
```

**EDIT 2:**
`grails -noreload run-app` and `grails clean` followed by a `grails run-app` both cause the server to launch properly, but then the the server shuts down after a short time (as I explained in my first edit):

```
grails -noreload run-app encountered a problem
```

The same happens when I delete the Ivy cache in `$USER/.grails/`.

The information on this error is a copy of the console output:

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.1
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application....
| Compiling 1 source files
  [groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Grails\test\target\classes
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Running Grails application

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:9000/test
```

Comment: Can you try it again with `grails run-app --verbose --stacktrace`? That would provide more information in the stacktrace.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847958/grails-app-fails-to-start-with-creation-of-bean-error (It might help someone in the future)

Answer (score 5):

Does the app start up with reloading ([spring-loaded agent](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-loaded)) disabled?

```
grails -noreloading run-app
```

A similar problem has been reported to Grails Jira as [GRAILS-9952](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9952). It would help fixing the problem if you can provide an test app that reproduces the problem. Please attach that to the jira issue.

Comment: GRAILS-9952 shows a workaround: delete the .slcache directory, for example "rm -rf ~/.grails/*/.slcache"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by my own. when i ran the app out of cmd it seemed to work. the reason for this was a missmatch between the groovy compilers i installed and GGTS was using.